# How to undo the 'npm run clean' script?

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

In react-boilerplate I ran the 'clean' command and deleted all of my work accidentally before committing to git.

I thought this would only delete the react-boilerplate related files that were unnecessary. How do I get these files back?

Answer (score 0):

That command is calling the `rm` delete command on the shell, so unless your work has ended up in your recycle bin I'm pretty sure it's gone forever.

Comment: ouchtown population me